# Shutdown a node from another node in ROS CPP

Tags: ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking for a way to shut down a node from another node.

```
from subprocess import call
call(["rosnode", "kill", "my_node"], shell=True)
```

The code above works fine with ROS Python. I am looking for the same in ROS CPP.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/294069/shutdown-a-node-from-another-node-in-ros-cpp/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2018-06-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Instead of doing a System call, I'd rather use a ROS Service which then Triggers a shutdown of the node in question.
This is way more portable than hard-coding a node Name that can easily be changed using a roslaunch tag.

---

**EDIT**

Create a ServiceServer in the node you want to shut down that triggers `ros::shutdown` and stops the node. Ideally, you wouldn't do the shutdown in the Service "callback" itself, but rather set some flag that shuts down the node after some short time. This will allow the Service to return a Response.

Thus, your calling node requires a ServiceClient with whatever Service type you see fit. I'd suggest [`std_srvs/Trigger`](http://docs.ros.org/api/std_srvs/html/srv/Trigger.html). But `std_srvs/Empty` would do as well.

---

Originally posted by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) with karma: 12390 on 2018-06-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-06-14**:
I like this suggestion. Just want to know, what do you mean by `use a ROS Service`? Do you want me to create a ROS service with empty request data? Can you please elaborate a bit more?

**Comment by [mgruhler](https://answers.ros.org/users/2647/mgruhler/) on 2018-06-14**:
see edit above

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-06-14**:
Interesting. *set some flag that shuts down the node `after some short time`* This seems tricky. How much is the short time?

**Comment by [srinskit](https://answers.ros.org/users/35857/srinskit/) on 2018-06-14**:
Do you have a `while` in the `main`?. Make the exit condition `ros::ok() && shutdown_flag`. Then just flip `shutdown_flag` in the callback.

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-06-14**:
Since my service server node is in Python and service client is in C++. I created a sample code in Python. Here is the [link](https://pastebin.com/2brp0JMq).

**Comment by [srinskit](https://answers.ros.org/users/35857/srinskit/) on 2018-06-14**:
So solved?

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-06-14**:
I think so. I haven't checked the code yet since I am out of the town. thanks again for the help.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use `system`.

`system(". PATH_TO_setup.sh ; rosnode kill sub");`

or if you want to use bash

`system("bash -c 'source PATH_TO_setup.bash ; rosnode kill sub'");`

replace `PATH_TO_setup` with your ROS source file like /opt/ros/melodic/setup.bash

---

Originally posted by [srinskit](https://answers.ros.org/users/35857/srinskit/) with karma: 11 on 2018-06-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2018-06-14**:
Need to test it. I used `system` but didn't provide `PATH_TO_setup.sh`.  It should work now!